# How to show details of Browser name and version in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

My scenario is users are login to Salesforce using different browsers like  google Internet explore, Mozilla,etc ..so I have to show the detils of which browser that is.. using lighting component

Comment: Methods of getting this are actually pretty unreliable, you may find you get better responses by editing your question to reflect what you're trying to accomplish with this. Are you trying to detect incompatible browsers?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion